# Location alert on ios

Tags: javascript, ios, geolocation, ionic-framework

I have a problem with my app on iOS created using ionic. 
In my home menu, when I press a button, my app tries to get my location and it shows me two alerts:
one in Italian(that's right) and one in english:

ITA:

[image: Italian alert]

ENGLISH:

[image: English alert]

The second alert is so ugly. I would like that the alert will be: "MYAPP vuole usare la tua posizione". How can I change the text of the second alert?

Comment: Could you please provide some code, which libraries you are using, and the version of your Cordova Location plugin?

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to wrap your Cordova location request inside an `ionicPlatform.ready` in your controller

```
.controller("MapController", ["$scope", "$cordovaGeolocation", "$ionicPlatform", function($scope, $cordovaGeolocation, $ionicPlatform) {

      $ionicPlatform.ready( function() {

            $cordovaGeolocation
              .getCurrentPosition()
              .then(function (position) {
                // do something
                }
              }, function(err) {
                // error
              });

      })

}])
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to know there are difference between Javascript alert and native alerts.

You could probably use `cordova notification` plugin and show the desire output inside it.

You could get plugin information from here:
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova_notification_notification.md.html

and download the plugin from github repo

Code implementation would be like:

```
$cordovaGeolocation
              .getCurrentPosition()
              .then(function (position) {
                //here call the notify method
                navigator.notification.alert(message, alertCallback, [title], [buttonName]) // instead of message pass the position 
                //title it so index.html will not be displaying
                }
              }, function(err) {
                // error
              });
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're worried about the looks you could try using a custom alert like sweet alert.
http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/

JS:

```
var script_0 = document.createElement('script');
script_0.src = "https://cdn.rawgit.com/t4t5/sweetalert/master/dist/sweetalert.min.js";
document.body.appendChild( script_0 );


var link_0 = document.createElement('link');
link_0.rel = "stylesheet";
link_0.type = "text/css";
link_0.href = "https://cdn.rawgit.com/t4t5/sweetalert/master/dist/sweetalert.css";
document.body.appendChild( link_0 );
```

or HTML:

```
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/t4t5/sweetalert/master/dist/sweetalert.min.js">     </script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/t4t5/sweetalert/master/dist/sweetalert.css">
```